# Material UI - conditional makeStyles animation by props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i want to set animation by condition, this is my code:
material version "^5.0.4"

[image]

[image]

and i got this warning log:
Warning: [JSS] Referenced keyframes rule "effect" is not defined.

Comment: Which version of `material-ui` You are using? Please provide such informations in the future :) This way you will save some of our time

Comment: @jkaczmarkiewicz i use material version "^5.0.4"

Comment: Did you find a solution? Have same error and same setup